# how to use case to combine spelling variations of an item in a table in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL tables, with deviations of the spellings of department names.  I'm needing to combine those using case to create one spelling of the location name. Budget_Rc is the only one with same spelling in both tables.  Here's an example:

```
Table-1                             table-2
Depart_Name     Room_Loc      Depart_Name     Room_Loc          
1. Finance_P1    P144          1. Fin_P1        P1444
2. Budget_Rc     R2c           2. Budget_Rc     R2c 
3. Payroll_P1_2  P1144         3. Finan_P1_1    P1444  
                               4. PR_P1_2       P1140
```

What I'm needing to achieve is for the department to be 1 entity, with one room location.  These should show as one with one room location in the main table (Table-1).

```
Depart_Name       Room_Loc          
1. Finance_P1     F144           
2. Budget_Rc      R2c            
3. Payroll_P1_2   P1144
```

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is name the only way you can join these departments together?  It is poor database design IMO not to have used some sort of ID to identify the departments.

Comment: Yes, I know, but trying to fix what was already done.

Comment: Do you have a typo `P144` instead of `P1444` ?

Comment: No not a typo, that's how it is in the table, and I'm trying to just create one room/location to fix this problem.  Thanks

Comment: Please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try a

```
DECLARE @AllSpellings TABLE(DepName VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @AllSpellings(DepName)
SELECT Depart_Name FROM tbl1 GROUP BY Depart_Name
UNION
SELECT Depart_Name FROM tbl2 GROUP BY Depart_Name;

SELECT DepName
FROM @AllSpellings
ORDER BY DepName
```

This will help you to find all existing values...

Now you create a clean table with all Departments with an `IDENTITY` ID-column.

Now you have two choices:

### In case you cannot change the table's layout

Use the upper `select`-statement to find all existing entries and create a mapping table, which you can use as indirect link

### Better: real FK-relation

Replace the department's names with the ID and let this be a `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE`

Comment: Thank you the select statement worked perfectly.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can more than one department be in a Room?

If so then its harder and you can't really write a dynamic query without having a list of all the possible one to many relationships such as Finance has the department key of FIN and they have these three names.  You will have to define that table to make any sort of relationship.

For instance:

```
DEPARTMENT TABLE

ID    NAME     ROOMID
FIN   FINANCE  P1444
PAY   PAYROLL  P1140

DEPARTMENTNAMES

ID DEPARTMENTNAME  DEPARTMENTID
1  Finance_P1      FIN
2  Payroll_P1_2    PAY
3  Fin_P1          FIN
```

etc...

This way you can correctly match up all the departments and their names. I would use this match table to get the data organized and normalized before then cleaning up all your data and then just using a singular department name. Its going to be manual but should be one time if you then clean up the data.

If the room is only ever going to belong to one department you can join on the room which makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Thank  you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since there does not appear any solid rule for mapping department names from table one to table two, the way I would approach this is to create a mapping table.  This mapping table will relate the two department names.

```
mapping

Depart_Name_1 | Depart_Name_2
-----------------------------
Finance_P1    | Fin_P1
Budget_Rc     | Budget_Rc
Payroll_P1_2  | PR_P1_2
```

Then, you can do a three-way join to bring everything into a single result set:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN mapping m
    ON t1.Depart_Name = m.Depart_Name_1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON m.Depart_Name_2 = t2.Depart_Name
```

It may seem tedious to create the `mapping` table, but it may be unavoidable here.  If you can think of a way to automate it, then this could cut down on the time spent there.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try every suggestion given.  Thanks